# How can I unit test in JavaScript? (the right way)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

I have been trying out different JavaScript unit testing libraries, but I still don't know what's the right way of doing this.

Is there a consensus on this subject?

For instance, I tried to write some tests for a modal window library with [QUnit](https://code.jquery.com/qunit/) (the unit testing library used by jQuery), but it has to be run in the browser, and it doesn't hide the effects I'm testing, or other annoying things like the alerts (I don't even know if that is possible in JavaScript). In a server-side language, any output generated by a test suite would be sent to a buffer and get discarded after each test.

If alerts, DOM manipulations, and that kind of things are not encapsulable in JavaScript unit testing, is writing tests worth the effort in this language?

Comment: Which libraries other than QUnit have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps you can find some suitable solution at https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Testing-frameworks . There are plenty of frameworks and such to pick from.

Answer (score 4):

Testing frontend code (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript) is not an easy task mostly thanks to cross-browser issues which require visual testing eg. making sure an element is correctly positioned in all browsers.

In order to test your JavaScript code you need to write it in a "testable" way. I personally found this blogpost very helpful: *[Writing Testable JavaScript](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/7/Writing-Testable-JavaScript)*

As for the actual testing, try to combine QUnit (which you are already using) with http://funcunit.com/. FuncUnit lets you open a HTML page and run tests on its DOM. There's an example on the home showing how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really annoyed by the DOM alterations and other effects (alert and prompt) you could use mocking and spying to ensure that those alterations are intended.

See [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) BDD that includes mocking and spying or [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/) for a standalone library.

Then you can just write a test like that (using Sinon):

```
var mock = sinon.mock(window);
mock.expects("alert").once().withExactArgs("foo");

alert("foo");

mock.verify();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like the idea of tying tests to a particular implementation. Suppose that the method that used to call the alert, now it doesn't. I would have to re-write the test to remove the expects('alert'). And it is too much work anyway.

Comment: Yeah that is the particular drawback of mocking in tests. And I agree that it is quite verbose.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper The whole point of doing the unit test is to assert a behavior. If you removed the `alert` from the main production code, and are forced to re-write the test because it fails, then you've correctly written the test! It's a good thing! It is notifying you of the change to your behavior, allowing you to correct the code or the test (depending on which is wrong). That is the whole point of unit tests and test driven development.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper That is a really odd comment. If you define a unit test to expect some behavior, and that behavior changes, the test should fail. Hence the purpose of a unit test. If you aren't testing for the behavior -- what are you testing for?

Comment: @BryanRowe Tests must not be tied to a particular implementation. In a good test, you don't care how the method being tested creates a result. You just test that the result is right. This way, if the implementation changes, but still throws the correct result, the test will pass.

Comment: What is "Jasmine BDD"? Is it a part of Jasmine with that name (the name of a tool)? Or something else?